# nginx connection refused remotely but localhost connects

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, lets-encrypt, linode, ubuntu-20.04

I have a strange problem with my Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

**Brief Background:**

I installed nginx and have been having alot of trouble with setting up letsencrypt. Attempting [this](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/where-should-well-known-acme-challenge-point/127497/4) with a statically served file, it continuously said the connection was refused. I reverted back to the original nginx default configuration, from localhost I see the page content "Welcome to NGINX" in HTML, but from multiple external sources, I keep getting connection refused.

**Configuration**
[Default NGINX configuration](https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/default-nginx-configuration-file-inside-sites-available-default) (copy + pasted directly)

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                # proxy_http_version 1.1;
                # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                # proxy_set_header Host $host;
                # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Using curl, I attempt to connect to port 80 from a remote site:

```
curl http://my-domain.com
```

responding with

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my-domain.com port 80: Connection refused
```

**Other Information:**

Active NGINX configuration added to sites-enabled

```
blms@my-domain:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 28 03:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Sep 28 03:29 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Sep 28 03:57 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

**Nginx Service Status: Active (no errors reported)**

```
blms@my-domain:~$ sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-09-28 03:57:26 UTC; 6min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 2901 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2912 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2913 (nginx)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1074)
     Memory: 2.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─2913 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             └─2914 nginx: worker process

Sep 28 03:57:25 my-domain.com systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 28 03:57:26 my-domain.com systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

**Confirmed HTTP Server listening on port 80:**

```
blms@my-domain:~$ sudo ss -tlp | grep http
LISTEN   0        511              0.0.0.0:http                  0.0.0.0:*       users:(("nginx",pid=2914,fd=6),("nginx",pid=2913,fd=6))
LISTEN   0        511                 [::]:http                     [::]:*       users:(("nginx",pid=2914,fd=7),("nginx",pid=2913,fd=7))
```

**iptables allowing all connections**

```
blms@my-domain:~$ sudo iptables -L -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 2936 packets, 238K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2567 packets, 393K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Frankly, I am quite stumped. I have also restarted to no avail.

Any suggestions?

**Update**

curl with IP address

```
curl x.y.z.a:80
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to x.y.z.a port 80: Connection refused
```

**curl localhost** on server itself

```
curl localhost
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is this server connected to the Internet?

Comment: Is the domain resolved correctly?

Comment: @MichaelHampton this is a linode VPS with a IPv4 & 6 connection

Comment: @GeraldSchneider it does, but for good measure, I resorted to using the IP address and that still refused (see update)

Comment: Are you in Linode's cloud firewall beta test?

Comment: @MichaelHampton see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the problem was one of my own.

the issue was I had not flushed my NAT table. I did this using `iptables -F -t nat`. This cleared the problem right up.

I am leaving this answer here in the hopes that it may help someone else.